# What's the proper way to open a file in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to open a txt file in IDLE but it gives me an error.
I can't figure out what happens to the f in my file name or why the single '\' becomes double in the error message.

```
>>>f=open('D:\programs\python 2.7.10\programs\foo.txt','r')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#94>", line 1, in <module>
    f=open('D:\programs\python 2.7.10\programs\foo.txt','r')
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: 'D:\\programs\\python 2.7.10\\programs\x0coo.txt'
```

Comment: You need to either escape your backslashes (double "\\") or use raw string syntax (`r"D:\...\foo.txt"`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Backslashes are used for escape sequences - in your case the culprit is `\f` which is the form-feed character. You can also use forward slashes on modern Windows systems as well as an alternative.

Use a raw string:

```
f=open(r'D:\programs\python 2.7.10\programs\foo.txt','r')
```

Ideally though, you should use the `with` statement so that it automatically closes the file in case of exceptions or when the with block exits, eg:

```
with open(r'D:\programs\python 2.7.10\programs\foo.txt','r') as f:
    # do stuff with `f`
```

Comment: A mostly irrelevant aside:  I used to convert my Windows paths to use forward slashes rather than using raw strings or doubling the backslashes.  Then Excel driven via COM object stopped allowing the forward slashes.  (I think the behavior changed in Excel 2010.)  Now I always just use raw strings when typing path literals.

Comment: @Steven interesting to know... thankfully I don't have the "pleasure" of having to deal with Windows on a day-to-day basis - but always handy to know something like that. Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

You have a funny character "\x0c" in your path. Its "f" in hex. Python doesn't understand. That's why ASCII gives an error. Rename your file into something nicer and you will be fine.

Comment: Python does *understand* it... it's just that the filename doesn't exist with that character in it. The problem is related to escape sequences...

Comment: Maybe. I never use windows and my filenames are fine.